# Why is jquery not working for scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried creating a scroll to the top button however the jquery command I implemented is not working. Nothing I do is making the scroll button take me to the top of the page. Does anyone know how I can fix it or what I am doing wrong?

```js
const scrolltotop = document.querySelector("#scrolltotop");

scrolltotop.addEventListener("click", function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, "slow");

});
```

```css
#scrolltotop {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #E7061B;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0 0 0 0.25);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  otline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#scrolltotop:active {
  background-color: #960204;
}
```

```html
<button id="scrolltotop">
        <i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i>
</button>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console window for any errors? Have you ensured that you have imported `jquery` before the script in your example? Are you adding the event to your button after the `DOM` has loaded?

Comment: first check if your click fires up

Comment: check if you have added jQuery, and make sure you have a decent height in the html body to see that scroll happening. Please provide some online link, so that we can see what is the exact issue. Script is fine. Have tried your code here(https://codepen.io/piupaulgit/pen/yLeRBvv), it is working as expected.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I have created enough height and the code seems to work on all the testing sites. I am using Adobe Dreamweaver and I think the software is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create enough height to scroll to? It works for me

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/sagive/n3L0kwuh/1/

easier Way:
https://jsfiddle.net/sagive/6mLugjkf/8/

Using jquery is easy:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('#scrollTop').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
    var scrollto    = $('#theTop'); 
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(scrollto).offset().top}, 1000);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe there is something wrong with the text editor I am using. The command seems to work for everyone else.

Comment: Did you have enough height in your document for a scroll?

Comment: dont forget to mark the correct answer so it would get closed. Best of luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can just use HTML and CSS, like this :

```
<div id="top"></div>
<!-- content page -->
<a href="#top">Go top</a>
```

And css :

```
body{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```